# Scraping a web page through a link.

Tags: python, loops, url, web-scraping

I am try to scrape a web page that you have to use a specific link to access the website. The issue is that this link takes you to the home page and that each product on the website has a unique url. My question is what would I do to access these product pages in order to scrape and download the PDF?

I am used to just looping thru the URLs directly but have never had to go thru one link to access the other urls. Any help would be great.

I am using Python and bs4.

Comment: If the url tags in the urls are fixed and always you'll find a url inside their divs. So, you can open the first URL, then extract the second URL, open it then extract the thirs url and so on ...

Comment: @Chiheb Nexus so would it just be a for loop directing you to the first link then another for loop directing you to the product link? Also I would have to run the first link before every product as it wont let you access it without the credentials first.